# Clarify the difference between over/above

Tags: prepositions

For instance:

> He lifted his bike above/over his head.

Please just clarify these prepositions with one example.

Comment: This might help with above vs. over: http://learnersdictionary.com/qa/above-and-over

Comment: There are dozens of different uses for each these words, which makes it difficult to explain them in our format. Prepositions are idiosyncratic. Can you provide a situation where you have seen more than one of them used, and why you find one or the other confusing?

Answer (score 2):

X is above Y - if Y were to look up, he/she/it would see X.  Usually but not always implies that there is some distance between X and Y.  If X and Y are numbers or measurements, X is larger than Y.

X is over Y - same as *above*, except X might be touching or covering Y.  If there is some distance between X and Y the implication is that the surface area of X is equal to or greater than Y, e.g. synonymous with *covers*.  E.g. "Clouds are over me" is appropriate because clouds are in the sky and have a large surface area.  "Clouds are above me" impiles that there's only a few clouds directly above you.

X upon Y - X is sitting on, hitting, or touching the top of Y, or very close and looking down on Y.